# how to add multi value array as a sub element of object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sub-array

I have two arrays and I want to add one array as a sub-element of the other array. There had some similar things but there not work for me.

```
const bodyContainer = [
    {
      messageId: 'msg001',
      message: 'test message 1'
    },
    {
      messageId: 'msg002',
      message: 'test message 2'
    },
    {
      messageId: 'msg003',
      message: 'test message 3'
    }];

const user = [{
      id: 'user01',
      chatHistory: //here I want to add the "bodyContainer" array as a sub array (not like a single-line string value)
    }];
```

how can I do this? Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: ```const user = [ { id: "user01", chatHistory: bodyContainer, }, ];``` just leave the array after ```:```

Comment: I tried it first. But it gave the result as ```chatHistory: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ]```

Comment: It is the correct output. I think you are using Nodejs. ```Terminal``` will not show everything compared to the Browser console. If you want to see your output clearly, you can use console.log ```JSON.stringify(user)``` instead.

Comment: Yeah. I'm using ```Node.js```. that's worked. Thank you for your support!